# Error while connecting to facebook server through the proxy

Tags: java, proxy, smack

I am having problems connecting to gtalk/facebook server from behind a proxy .In my loginservlet under doPost I specify the proxy settings before making a connection with the servers.The code is as follows:

```
package web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
  import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
  import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
  import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
  import org.jivesoftware.smack.proxy.ProxyInfo;

  import dao.MySASLDigestMD5Mechanism;

   public class LoginFacebookServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public LoginFacebookServlet() {
    super();

  }
 XMPPConnection connection;
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userName = request.getParameter("usrnm_fb");
    String password = request.getParameter("password_fb");

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();

    SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5", MySASLDigestMD5Mechanism.class);
    //SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5", 0);

  ProxyInfo proxyInfo = new ProxyInfo(ProxyInfo.ProxyType.HTTP,"proxy.xxx.com"  "talk.google.com",   port, "username", "password");
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com",5222,proxyInfo);
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
   config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    try {
        connection.connect();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        connection.login(userName, password);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(connection.isAuthenticated());
   // System.out.println("Welcome!!you are now connected to facebook");
}
```

}

When I run the application it still gives me 500 status error.Following is the stack trace

```
 XMPPError connecting to chat.facebook.com:5222.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError      connecting to chat.facebook.com:5222.
  -- caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:900)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1415)
at web.LoginFacebookServlet.doPost(LoginFacebookServlet.java:52)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Nested Exception: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at              org.jivesoftware.smack.proxy.DirectSocketFactory.createSocket(DirectSocketFactory.java:28)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:888)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1415)
at web.LoginFacebookServlet.doPost(LoginFacebookServlet.java:52)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at       org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
 Apr 26, 2011 11:32:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet LoginFacebookServlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:382)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:349)
at web.LoginFacebookServlet.doPost(LoginFacebookServlet.java:57)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I checked to see  if any thing more was there to add for by passing proxy but am unable to understand as to where am I going wrong?

Thanks:)

Comment: Try [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0085.html)

Answer (score 2):

XMPP != HTTP so there's no reason to expect that an HTTP proxy will be used by an XMPP client. However, it seems like Smack has added [HTTP proxy support (in addition to SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 proxy support they had earlier](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/proxy/ProxyInfo.ProxyType.html)). The [`ConnectionConfiguration`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/ConnectionConfiguration.html#ConnectionConfiguration%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20org.jivesoftware.smack.proxy.ProxyInfo%29) can accept a [ProxyInfo](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/proxy/ProxyInfo.html#ProxyInfo%28org.jivesoftware.smack.proxy.ProxyInfo.ProxyType,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) parameter.

As far as I can tell from the [JavaDocs](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/), this is what you need to do:

```
ProxyInfo proxyInfo = new ProxyInfo(ProxyInfo.ProxyType.HTTP, "proxy.xxx.com", 8080, "username", "password")
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("facebook.com", 5222, proxyInfo);
XMPPConnection conn = new XMPPConnection(config);
conn.connect();
```

Also, for future questions, please note

1. Although your question is tagged 'Smack' you posted no Smack specific code. The lines showing use of the `URLConnection` are pointless since that's not where your connection is failing.
2. Your question title indicates Google Talk, however everything else refers to Facebook. This is confusing and unclear questions or code that is NOT what you're actually working with will most likely lead to frustration for you and other members. As far as possible, you should post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @no.good.at.coding I tried your solution but it still gives me the same error as mentioned above...any ideas why??

Comment: @xoxoxo If it gives you the same error it looks like either your code isn't correct and isn't using the proxy or your proxy does not allow connections to Facebook.com. I just tested this out for Google Talk and Facebook chat with and without a proxy and it worked just fine. Please edit your question and post your updated code and the complete stack trace.

Comment: @ no.good.at.coding-No success in by passing the proxy..I have updated the code and stack trace..

Comment: @xoxoxo Are you sure your proxy allows connections to Facebook? And does it allow connections to ports other than 80/443? I can't think of any other reasons why this might be failing.

Comment: You might be able to troubleshoot this by trying to connect through the proxy using an XMPP client that supports HTTP proxies and seeing if that works. If not, you have a problem with your proxy not your code.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding-k I will try it out and let you know...thanks:)